# The same component render two times

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want render the same component **instance** of `<Child />` two times in `<Parent />` component.

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import Parent from './Parent';

render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Parent.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Child from './Child';

const child = <Child />

export default () => {
  return (
    <>
      {child}
      {child}
    </>
  )
}
```

Child.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function generateRandomString() {
  return Math.random().toString();
}

export default () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState(generateRandomString());

  function onClickHandler() {
    setText(generateRandomString());
  }

  return (
    <div onClick={onClickHandler}>text: {text}</div>
  )
}
```

Is it possible to do?

Comment: You can just return `<Child />` twice in your parent component.

Comment: @SachinVerma, okay, but every time it will be new component instance with new state.

Comment: May we know why you want to do so?

Comment: @PriyeshDiukar, okay so above is simple example only. I'm working on big React application and I have two components - first for desktop and second for mobile. Both components are display on screen but one has `display: none`. When user resize window, I switch display of components between mobile and desktop in CSS (normally RWD). I want to render input on every of this components with the same state (two times). Sorry for my English :)

Comment: an instance of a component can only exist in one place at any given time. you can have as many instances of child as you like but the idea of using same instance in multiple places is both irrational and impossible in react

Comment: @qweqweqweqwe I still do not get the problem here. You should ideally have state store all your important data. Then it should not matter how many instances of components you create.
you quoted "every time it will be new component instance with new state"
I am trying to understand What is the problem if you get a new state?.
If you are worried about state modification. Try using a much global redux state instead. Where you both desktop and mobile instances can refer to the modifications.

Comment: @qweqweqweqwe if you still want to get the same state on both the Child component. You can add this line `<div onClick={onClickHandler}>text: {text}</div>` once more in your `Child.js` component and call it in your `Parent.js` component once. Or, you can create use the render Props method and again return two child components within the same render. Still confused why you would want that

Answer (score 1):

You are treating component as value. Just change your parent.js as follow.

```
import React from 'react';
import Child from './Child';
export default () => {
  return (
    <div>
     <Child/>
     <Child/>
    <div/>
 )
}
```

Comment: Okay, but every of <Child /> has different state (not the same instance).

Comment: @qweqweqweqwe Yes as they are two individual components. I read your comment below the question. I am curious why are you rendering two same components for two different views?